# Method blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, callback

I have recently created a helper method to throttle the speed of property changed event in order to save the data to my local database with a given delay. The only problem I got with it is that the method is apparently not running asynchronously and blocking my UI thread.

To test it, I have attached the event in my `SettingsViewModel` to the `PercentageSliderViewModel`:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : BaseVM
{
    public PercentageSliderViewModel Activity { get; set; }

    [...]

    public SettingsViewModel() {
        Activity.PropertyChanged += CreateThrottledCallback(Save, 1000);
    }

    [...]

    public async Task Save()
    {
        // Save data
    }
}
```

This is my helper method:

```
public PropertyChangedEventHandler CreateThrottledCallback(
            Func<Task> callback, int throttle = 1000)
{
    bool throttling = false;
    bool callFinal = false;

    return async(s, e) =>
    {
        if (throttling)
        {
            callFinal = true;
            return;
        }

        throttling = true;

        await callback?.Invoke();

        await Task.Delay(throttle).ContinueWith(_ => throttling = false);

        if (callFinal)
        {
            await callback?.Invoke().ContinueWith(_ => callFinal = false);
        }
    };
}
```

Even though the throttling is working fine, when I move the slider from left to right and the callback occurs it is 'freezing' for a small amount of time.

Debugging shows that it is running on the UI thread.

How can run `CreateThrottledCallback` method asynchronously so it wont block my main thread then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your `Save` method really does and whether it's actually a truly asynchronous method. You could try to execute it an a background thread in your `CreateThrottledCallback` method:

```
if (callback != null)
    await Task.Run(() => callback.Invoke());
```

Comment: `Save` calls the Dapper's [UpdateAsync](http://dapper-tutorial.net/async#queryasync) method. Running this in Task does solve the problem, however I'm not sure why do I have to do that, since called methods are asynchronous by themselves... Running one task per second is slighty expensive operation.

Comment: @Rusco: "methods are asynchronous by themselves". Apparently they are not if the block the calling thread. Remember that an async method runs synchronously until it hits an await statement. This might be an issue, especially in UI applications. That's why it's usually "safer" to call the entire method on a background thread. The default task scheduler uses the task pool to schedule the task so it shouldn't consume more resources than it can actually handle.

Comment: Yeah, I will accept this answer because it explains everything basically. Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it has nothing to do with UI, you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This will avoid capturing the current synchronization context and the task will run on `TaskScheduler.Default` thread pool context.

```
await callback().ConfigureAwait(false);
```